# Running json-2-csv npm using as input a json file saved to desktop

Tags: json, node.js, csv

I try to use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-2-csv) from npm in order to convert a json file I have saved to my desktop.

However I can't understand how to do it because I am not an original programmer.

I have installed the npm and

```
npm install json-2-csv
```

after this steps I can't understand how can I import my json file.

If there is anyone who could help me with the following steps or screenshots it could be very very useful for me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your json file to root directory of your Node.js application and rename it to data.json.

Then create app.js file in the same directory with this code:

```
var converter = require('json-2-csv');
var fs = require('fs');

var jsonData = require('./data.json');

var json2csvCallback = function (err, csv) {
    if (err) throw err;

    fs.writeFile("./data.csv", csv, function(err) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("data.csv file has been saved.");
    }); 
};

converter.json2csv(jsonData, json2csvCallback);
```

It requires data.json file from the root app directory (will work only with a valid JSON, otherwise you will find an error description in the console). If all ok, it will convert JSON to CSV using json-2-csv module and will save data.csv file with the result still in the root app directory.

Just try to run it with: node app.js